# Delete/Update Many-to-Many tables

Tags: python, mysql, peewee

I'm having challenge deleting and updating many to many tables, below are the model and code

```
class Job(Model):
    """docstring for Jobs"""
    url = CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    title = TextField()
    description = TextField()
    sponsor = CharField(max_length=100)
    location = CharField(max_length=100)
    uuid = CharField(max_length=150)
    timestamp = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)

    class Meta:
        database = DATABASE
        order_by = ('-timestamp',)

class Category(Model):
    """docstring for JobCategory"""
    category = CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    cat_slug = TextField()
    jobs = ManyToManyField(Job, related_name='categories')
    class Meta:
        database = DATABASE
JobsCategory = Category.jobs.get_through_model()
```

Here is the method to delete queries, actually it work but it only delete a row, how can I delete multiple rows

```
def updateEntries(self):
      try:
            query = models.Job.select().where(models.Job.timestamp < datetime.date.today()-datetime.timedelta(days=2)):
            return jobs.execute()  # Returns the number of rows deleted. delete_instance()
        except models.DoesNotExist:
            pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#ManyToManyField.remove

But you can also do things like:

```
JobsCategory.delete().where(
    (JobsCategory.job == job_obj) &
    (JobsCategory.category == category_obj)).execute()
```

Comment: sorry for the mistake in updateEntries method, my intention was to delete all entries in Job table and everything that associate with it using this code   query = models.Job.delete().where(models.Job.timestamp < datetime.date.today()-datetime.timedelta(days=2))    query.execute() but generate peewee.IntegrityError: (1451, 'Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`career`.`category_job_through`, CONSTRAINT `category_job_through_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`job_id`) REFERENCES `job` (`id`))') what can i do?